# What is wrong with this script

Tags: lua, roblox

In a game I am making there is a sell area, this is the script. I set up a series of print statements to see where the error occurs, and it occurs when it checks the Clouds.Value, can you help me fix the script, I don't know what is causing the error.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    print(hit.Name)
    if game.Players:FindFirstChild(hit.Parent.Name) then
        print("Found")
        local plr = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        local stats = plr:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
        if stats then
        print("Working")
            local Cash = stats:FindFirstChild("CloudCoins")
            print("Cash")
            local Clouds = stats:FindFirstChild("Clouds")
            print("Clouds")
            if Clouds.Value > 0 then
                print("Value")
                Cash.Value = Cash.Value + Clouds.Value
                Clouds.Value = 0
            else
                print("Error")
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the problem is in the tool that adds the clouds to the player, It is not updating the server.